# Vuejs component missing computed property

Tags: vue.js, instance, computed-properties

Our team created a plugin that adds a beforeCreate mixin. This mixin adds a computed property to the component instance. It works perfect in one project, but in another project `this.$options.computed` is undefined. Both are running 2.6.11, and the component is actually another plugin for a tempate, so it's the exact same component code. I can't figure out why `computed` would be defined in one project, but not the other or for any vue component instance.

```
function plugin (Vue, options = {}) {
  Vue.mixin({
    beforeCreate () {
    ...
    this.$options.computed[computedName] = computedFns(name)
    // above line throws cannot set value to undefined
    ...
}

function computedFns (name) {
  return {
    get () {
      return this[name] === undefined ? this.$data[DATA_PREFIX + name] : this[name]
    },
    set (value) {
      if (this[name] === undefined) {
        this.$data[DATA_PREFIX + name] = value
      }
      this.$emit(`update:${name}`, value)
    }
  }
}
```

For kicks and giggles I listed out all the properties of `this.$options` as referenced in the mixin, and sure enough, computed is missing when used in the second project:

```
::::: parent
::::: _parentVnode
::::: propsData
::::: _parentListeners
::::: _renderChildren
::::: _componentTag
::::: components
::::: directives
::::: filters
::::: _base
::::: beforeCreate
::::: destroyed
::::: props
::::: data
::::: watch
::::: mounted
::::: methods
::::: render
::::: staticRenderFns
::::: _compiled
::::: _scopeId
::::: _ssrRegister
::::: __file
::::: name
::::: _Ctor
```

But it's there in the first project:

```
::::: parent
::::: _parentVnode
::::: propsData
::::: _parentListeners
::::: _renderChildren
::::: _componentTag
::::: components
::::: directives
::::: filters
::::: _base
::::: beforeCreate
::::: destroyed
::::: data
::::: computed
::::: created
::::: props
::::: watch
::::: mounted
::::: methods
::::: render
::::: staticRenderFns
::::: _compiled
::::: _scopeId
::::: _ssrRegister
::::: __file
::::: name
::::: _Ctor
```

Comment: If `computed` is not defined - perhaps you should create it as an empty object first, before adding the `computedName` key ?

Comment: I could, but I'm concered something is wrong with the second project given it is not there by default.

Comment: It is possible that Vue does not define it if there are no computed properties in the given component.

Comment: I've been pondering that, but it's the exact same component (because it's a plugin) in both projects that is attempting to use the mixin.

Comment: You can try to define a dummy computed property in the component where you are trying to inject the mixin - thus you will guarantee the `computed` key in `$options` is always present.

Comment: I added a dummy computed, and it worked fine, but the other project's use of the *same component* (I verified it was the same code without a computed property) doesn't require the dummy for computed to be available.

Comment: That is why I recommended to first check whether the `computed` is defined - and if it is not, simply define it before adding your `computedFns`. Such safeguards are quite common in JavaScript.